# Setting up webpack hot load / HMR for static pages

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpack-hmr

I know the title doesn't make too much sense. But please bear with me.

I am setting up React for a legacy Rails app which is using the good old static ERBs. Due to the scale, I have to move towards SPA slowly, meaning swapping out components on the page.

My current setup is using webpack to compile a bundle file, the output it to the assets directory. Then just load that bundle file on the page relying on assets pipeline for caching (not idea, but enough to get started). On pages that have react component, I will have a `<div>` for appending a certain component. e.g.:

```
<body>
  <div>some other erb, html stuffs</div>
  <div>more other erb, html stuffs</div>

  <div id='react-component-1'></div>
  <div id='react-component-2'></div>
</body>
```

This works as a basic setup. But to speed up the development, I'd like to setup hot loading. However, because I am not serving the entire page, I have to actually write the bundle file to disk so that rails can pick it up. And this also prevent me from using webpack-dev-server.

Is there any way to setup HMR in this setup?

Possible options:

1. Reloading the bundle file every now and then (but I've tried this by appending new script tag, and removing the old one. Although the script file is downloaded (200 status from network tab), the updated scripts are not being loaded)
2. Refreshing the page programmatically, and store serialize state in session storage (this won't be ideal, because it also refreshes other parts of the static page)
3. Maybe there is a way to serve only the bundle file through webpack-dev-server?

**Edit**

I followed @SamHH answer and it seems it's not able to load the bundle file (404). My path config is a little quirky.

I have my webpack output path to

```
'../../app/assets/webpack/admin'
```

publicPath to

```
/admin/
```

But a matching path set in `proxy` option didn't quite work. And from network tab, looks like it was loading from `/javascripts/...`

Webpack config:

```
const config = {
  entry: {
    bundle: './apps/appsRegistration',
    vendor: VENDOR_LIBS
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: pathLib.resolve(__dirname, '../../app/assets/webpack/admin'),
    publicPath: '/admin/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({ NODE_ENV: 'development' }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor'
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  externals: {
    react: 'React',
    'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
    redux: 'Redux',
    'react-redux': 'ReactRedux',
    'redux-thunk': 'ReduxThunk'
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 9000,
    disableHostCheck: true,
    proxy: {
      '!/admin/**': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000',
        secure: false
      }
    },
    hot: true
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `webpack-dev-server` and proxy all non-assets back to your Rails app. So if your rails app is on `http://localhost:8000`, you tell the Webpack config to proxy all devServer requests that don't match your assets glob back to that address. Then you would load and develop on the Webpack dev server port.

For example, if you set your Webpack config as follows `output.publicPath: '/dev-assets/'` then you can do the following:

```
devServer: {
    port: 9000,
        proxy: {
            '!/dev-assets/**': {
                target: `http://localhost:8000`,
                secure: false
            }
        },
        hot: true
    },
}
```

Then just load `http://localhost:9000` when developing.

Comment: when you say load `port:9000` when developing, do you mean loading that for the client side page?

Comment: Yes. You load in your browser the URL that Webpack produces, in this case `http://localhost:9000`. This will proxy all non-asset requests, per the glob, over to your Rails app at (presumably) `http://localhost:8000`, so everything else continues to work as if you hadn't changed ports.

Comment: sounds like a plan. I am going to test this out and come back. thanks

Comment: the proxy is working. however, seems hot loading isn't taking place. I am testing by adding a `console.log`

Comment: For hot reloading you'll also need to add `new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()` to your `plugins` array in the Webpack config.

Comment: I've already added that plugin. and also running with `--hot --inline`

Comment: I think the issue might be the path configuration. Please see my edit

Comment: after further investigation, seems the problems is still the page itself is not served by webpack dev server.

Comment: The proxy glob needs to match `output.publicPath`, not `output.path`.

Comment: thanks for following up. But I am still seeing the same issue. I updated the question with my webpack config. Mind if you can help take a look?

Comment: Try adding `if (module.hot) module.hot.accept()` to the root of your client JS.